# Trigger bamboo plan from bitbucket Webhooks

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, webhooks, bamboo

I spent a couple of hours to figure out why I'm not able to trigger a webhook from bitbucket to bamboo,  I found nothing yet

Issue:
I want to track when a PR is merged or a branch is deleted which as I see I'm not able to track this stuff from bamboo, so I need to have a webhook in bitbucket and call a bamboo reset api  base on this page if there is no better idea.

base on this page I thought I can trigger a webhook 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/triggering-a-bamboo-build-from-bitbucket-cloud-using-webhooks-873949130.html

But this solution is now working because each time I got this error message

```
{"message":"Anonymous user can't access this resource. If it should be available, modify anonymous user permissions at Administration > Security settings","status-code":401}
```

The only access we have for Anonymous group is **view** which I see this is not enough to call this API from bitbucket
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-permissions-369296034.html

So I don't know what to do and how to track if a PR is merged or a branch is deleted.

I would appreciate to tell me what the problem is

FYI: bamboo and bitbucket version is the latest one

Answer (score 1):

What is your Bamboo version? This issue was covered at Bamboo 6.7.0. At Bamboo > Administration > Security settings you can grant/deny access of anonymous users to given webhook

Comment: It's the lastest version, I can change the privileges for the anonymous user but that is not a secure way.

Comment: It's anonymous user access to this endpoint specifically. You can configure IP mask for Bitbucket Cloud if you want avoid random users trigger your build by REST call

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to enable triggers for anonymous users. Also, as @Hamed mentioned, allowing anonymous access is not feasible in some environments. The problem is we cannot even go with `<User>:<Password>@<Bamboo URL>` and that strips off the auth details.

One possible way of doing this is to keep a `proxy` between Bitbucket and Bamboo and then add the Authentication headers at the proxy level.